# Validación con formvalidation en BootstrapFileInput

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, bootstrap, formularios

Estoy usando 2 plugins en un sistema (PYTHON-DJANGO). El primero es formvalidation y el segundo es el Bootstrap File Input.

Cuando hago un nuevo.

```
$("#imagen").fileinput({
                language: "es",
                maxFileCount: 1,
                minFileCount: 1,
                initialPreviewAsData: true,
                overwriteInitial: false,
                browseIcon: "<i class=\"fa fa-search\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> ",
           });
```

El problema sucede cuando hago un editar en un registro de una tabla traigo la imagen de nuevo al componente con el initialPreview,initialPreviewConfig,etc;

Este es el codigo cuando hago un editar

```
$("#imagen").fileinput({
                language: "es",
                maxFileCount: 1,
                minFileCount: 1,
                validateInitialCount : false,
                browseIcon: "<i class=\"fa fa-search\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> ",
                initialPreview: [
                   "{% static foto %}"
                ],
                initialPreviewConfig: [{caption: '{{ name }}', showDelete: false}],
                initialPreviewAsData: true,
                initialPreviewFileType: 'image',
                overwriteInitial: true,
                initialPreviewCount: 1,
                initialCaption: '{{ name }}',
            });
```

Carga con normalidad la imagen..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el problema radica que cuando ya valido con el plugin formvalidation el cual lo tengo de la siguiente manera la validación.

```
imagen: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Seleccione una imagen'
                },
                file: {
                    extension: 'jpeg,jpg,png',
                    type: 'image/jpeg,image/png',
                    message: 'El archivo seleccionado no es válido'
                }
            }
        }
```

Cuando hago un nuevo sale normalmente validado y tood bien pero cuando hago el editar sale lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El funcionamiento es correcto, trata de no cargar ese validador en el update.

Si estas usando la misma template añade una variable que te diga que estas haciendo y con un if haz que no ejecute ese validador.

o si estas usando templates diferentes simplemente no llames a ese validador.

Podrías complicar la cosa validando o el input o la existencia de la imagen, pero si ya lo haces en el formulario de creación, puedes dar por-supuesta la existencia de la imagen.

También podrías cargar la ruta de la imagen en ese input, hacerlo deshabilitado para que no lo pudieran modificar mas que eliminando y añadiendo otro.

Answer (score 0):

Así lo solucione..

```
introducir el código aquí<script>
    var action = '{{ action }}';
    var resp = false;
    $(function () {
    switch (action){
       case 'edit':
           $("#imagen").fileinput({
                language: "es",
                browseIcon: "<i class=\"fa fa-search\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> ",
                initialPreview: [
                   "{% static foto %}"
                ],
                initialPreviewConfig: [{caption: '{{ name }}', showDelete: false}],
                initialPreviewAsData: true,
                initialPreviewFileType: 'image',
                overwriteInitial: true,
                initialCaption: '{{ name }}',
            })
            .on('filecleared', function(event) {
                $('#formulario').formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'imagen', true);
                $('#formulario').formValidation('revalidateField', 'imagen');
            })
           .on('change', function(event) {
                 $('#formulario').formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'imagen', true);
            });
            break;
       case 'add':
           resp = true;
           $("#imagen").fileinput({
                language: "es",
                overwriteInitial: true,
                browseIcon: "<i class=\"fa fa-search\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> ",
           }).on('filecleared', function(event) {
               $('#formulario').formValidation('revalidateField', 'imagen');
           });
       }
    });
</script>
```

Validacion del plugin de formvalidation

```
introducir el código aquíimagen: {
            enabled : resp,
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Seleccione una imagen'
                },
                file: {
                    maxFiles : 1,
                    minFiles : 1,
                    extension: 'jpeg,jpg,png',
                    type: 'image/jpeg,image/png',
                    message: 'El archivo debe ser en formato de imagen | La cantidad de archivos a subir debe ser de 1'
                }
            }
        }
```

https://algorisoft.com/